# What is the word for a specific release of an academic journal?

Tags: single-word-requests, academia

For a journal which is published periodically (e.g. monthly) what is the world for a specific period's published version?  For example, "The past ten _____'s of *Nature* have each contained an article on colloid synthesis."  Maybe "release," "edition," or "publication?"  None of those seem quite right: I associate "release" with something more like a press, movie, or album release, "edition" with a [variant of the method of publication](http://www.bmj.com/about-bmj/academic-edition) or a book with relatively minor revisions from the previous edition (as opposed to a journal, which has completely new content every time), and "publication" with a specific article within the journal.  A specific release of an academic journal is usually indicated by the journal number (e.g. "*Nature* **5**, [page] 514 (1983)"), but it sounds funny to describe a specific release as a "number."

Comment: *edition*, *number*, *issue*, *version*. Different academic journals use different words.

Comment: Note that in the citation example you give, the numeral **5** would be the *volume* number; the number in brackets would be the *issue* number, and the numeral 514 would be the *page* number of that issue where the article starts. Volume numbers usually correspond to years that the journal has been publishing (Volume 1 would be all issues published in the first year of the journal's existence). Issue numbers might be continuous, or they might start over every year.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The word you want is ***issue***.  Academic journals publish issues that are organized by volume number and issue number.  Scholarly citations note both volume and issue along with page numbers and date.

For example:

> The April 2016 issue of *Psychoanalytic Quarterly* (Volume 85, Issue 2, Pages 269–561) focuses on a special topic, "Is Truth Relevant?".